# Lives Implementation in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I begun the trek into Unity2D development a few months ago, so i'm still fairly new to all the unity engine jargon. In my game, I decided to implement the use of 'Lives'. I scripted out what (in my eyes) *should* work but every time the player dies instead of decrementing the lives counter and restarting it at the scene, it immediately loads the scene 1 (i.e. the GameOver screen) Is my logic here on this page incorrect or is there just a better way overall to handle lives than PlayerPrefs? (ALSO: Its worth mentioning that the Lives are instantiated/sent to playerprefs in the player script, I don't figure I need to include that one here)

This is the main block of code on my destroyer objects' script to account for 'death':

```
public static int lives;

void Start()
{
    lives = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("lives");
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    //If the trigger happens to be tagged as a 'Player', does this.
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        lives--;
        if (lives < 0)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
            SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
        } else
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("lives", lives);
        }

    }

    if (other.gameObject.transform.parent)
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
    } 
    else {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional Info: The lives are set to 3 initially in the player script.

Comment: Your logic seems to be correct here. It seems the initial value of `lives` is not being set correctly, or, it's since being loaded from `PlayerPrefs`, maybe the value is being overwritten.
Try checking the actual value of `lives` before decrementing(with a `Debug.Log` or using a debugger).

Comment: Logic seem right but i think you forget to swithOn is Trigger field from Inspector which is under the Collider area. You should click to isTrigger field cause you are using OnTriggerEnter. It will be very good if you check the differences between onTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Check the collider area]

As I mentinoned in comment, I think you forget to swithOn `isTrigger` field from Inspector which is under the `Collider` area.

Probably you thought like you are using onCollisionEnter. Also if you check the differences between `OnTriggerEnter` and `OnCollisionEnter` it will be very helpful.

Comment: My problem actually was in the player controller script; the line where i send the initial lives counter to playerprefs was incorrect. Ive already set it as a trigger. However, i chose this as the answer because after fixing it, the OnTriggerEnter2D function was making it to where lives were decremented more than once, so I need to look more into those differences. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

As @Ugur Tufekci answers, But make sure to add **BoxCollider2d** not Box Collider.The simple box collider is `3d` but your are detecting that `onTriggerEnter2D` that means 2d box collider has to be added

Comment: yes I open scene for screenshot and I forget he is working on 2d objects but i think he knows the difference :)

Comment: Yeah!. You should clear the difference between `trigger` and `collider`.